# How Remove extra tag in xml in php

Tags: php, xml

Here I generate on xml dynamically but in this i got the xml but in the last extra two tags came.

Here My xml

```
<Main>
<Mainrow>
<code>xxxx</code>
<itemname>AAAAA</itemname>
<qty>5.000</qty>
</Mainrow>
</Main>/Mainrow></Main>
```

My loop

```
$stock_txt = '<Main>';
            foreach($results as $key => $datas){
                   $stock_txt .= '<Mainrow>';
                    foreach($datas as $val=>$res){
                        $stock_txt .= '<'.$val.'>'.$res.'</'.$val.'>';
                    }
                        $stock_txt .= '</Mainrow>';
                }
           $stock_txt .= '</Main>';
           $dom->loadXML($stock_txt);
           $dom->save($myFile); // myFile -- my path to save file
           fwrite($fh, $stock_txt);
```

how to trim the last

**/Mainrow and Main**

I tried

> substr($stock_txt,-22); but failed to get the XML generation

Thanks in advance

Comment: `</Main>/Mainrow>` that is buggy syntax, check that first

Comment: Please use `XMLWriter` for making XML Data.

Comment: hi, I when i generate the xml using that loop I got like that </Main>/Mainrow> at last. how to remove or is any mistake in my loop

Comment: The `loop` looks fine. Cant see any errors there. Try to change this: `'>'.$res.'<` to `'><![CDATA['.$res.']]><`  and look what happens.

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions Still Last I get last two tags.
$stock_txt .= '<'.$val.'><![CDATA['.$res.']]></'.$val.'>';

Comment: What does `fwrite($fh, $stock_txt);` if you already using `$dom->save($myFile);`. And normaly this line `$stock_txt .= '</Main>';` adds only one `</Main>` into the xml. Is this maybe old data or other runnning code?

Comment: Thanks Dude I got it 
fwrite($fh, $stock_txt); if you already using $dom->save($myFile); the problem in that.  thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not create XML as text, use DOM or XMLWriter methods to create/add the nodes. You load your XML string into DOM and save it. So why not use DOM methods from the start:

```
$results = [
  [
    'code' => 'xxxx',
    'itemname'=> 'AAAAA',
    'qty'=> '5.000'
  ]
];

$document = new DOMDocument();
$main = $document->appendChild($document->createElement('Main'));
foreach ($results as $datas) {
  $row = $main->appendChild($document->createElement('Mainrow'));
  foreach ($datas as $name => $value) {
     $row
       ->appendChild($document->createElement($name))
       ->appendChild($document->createTextNode($value));
  }
}

$document->formatOutput = TRUE;
//$document->save($myFile);
echo $document->saveXml();
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Main>
  <Mainrow>
    <code>xxxx</code>
    <itemname>AAAAA</itemname>
    <qty>5.000</qty>
  </Mainrow>
</Main>
```